# General form of a series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, number-theory, numerical-methods

I was just browsing some series when I found this

Smarandache sequences are any of a number of simply generated integer sequences resembling those considered in published works by Smarandache such as the consecutive number sequences and Euclid numbers.Some other "Smarandache" sequences are given below.

The concatenation of $n$ copies of the integer $n$: $1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,...$  For $n\leq9$, they have the simple formula

$n$th term=$\dfrac{n(10^n-1)}{9}$

Similarly can we find the nth term of the series $1,333,55555,7777777...$??
e.g. can we find the $2016$th no of the series??

i tried it
but i can only find upto low range $(100-200)$th terms by using simple methods.

please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer to your question is simply $2016\cdot\sum\limits_{n=0}^{2015}10000^n$... Having said that, the first sequence you present and the second sequence you present, do not seem quite of the same form (perhaps you meant $1,3,3,3,5,5,5,5,5,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,\dots$ in the second sequence?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple:

$$\begin{align}
1 & =\sum_{n=1}^11\times10^{n-1} \\
333 & =\sum_{n=1}^33\times10^{n-1} \\
55555 & =\sum_{n=1}^55\times10^{n-1} \\
\vdots \\
a_{2016} & = \sum_{n=1}^{4031}4031\times10^{n-1} \\
& =447\underbrace{888\dots888}_{4028\ 8's}441 \\
\end{align}
$$